# Newbie in AWS Glacier - how to connect to my storage and upload files there via PowerShell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I'm a newbie with S3 and would like to know step by step how to connect, upload and read file(s) to my S3 Glacier storage via PowerShell? Link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-GLCVault.html looks very uninformative and convoluted regarding credentials to be used for connecting, and also has no samples to play with. Could anybody describe me step by step how to connect from my PowerShell console and do all the described steps for S3? AWSPowerShell.NetCore was installed on my Win machine, so cmdlets seem to be available. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are two 'versions' of Glacier on AWS. The original Amazon Glacier uses Vaults and Archives. It is very slow and extremely difficult to use. Later, Amazon S3 introduced Glacier 'storage classes' that gave all the benefits of Glacier pricing, without all the bad bits. Plus, it is cheaper than the 'original' Amazon Glacier. Your Question mentions 'vault', so it is probably referring to the 'original' Glacier. I recommend you do _not_ use the 'original' Glacier. Instead, just store the data in S3 as normal, but use a Glacier Storage Class.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**.

To create a vault and upload files to AWS Glacier using PowerShell, you can follow these steps:

- **Configure AWS Tools**: You need to set up your AWS credentials (access key ID, secret access key, region).

  ```
  Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey <your-access-key> -SecretKey <your-secret-key> -StoreAs <credential-name>
  Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName <credential-name>
  ```
- **Create a Vault**: Use the `New-GLCVault` command to create a vault in Glacier. Replace `vault-name` with your desired vault name.

  ```
  New-GLCVault -VaultName <vault-name>
  ```
- **Upload Files to the Vault**: Use the `aws glacier upload-archive` command to upload files to the vault. Replace `vault-name` with your vault name and file-path with the path to the file you want to upload.

  ```
  $filePath = "<file-path>"
  $folderPath = "<folder-path>"
  $vaultName = "<vault-name>" 
  Write-GLCArchive -VaultName $vaultName -FilePath $filePath -FolderPath $folderPath
  ```

  If you want to specify a description for the uploaded archive, you can use the `-Description` parameter:

  ```
  $archiveDescription = "Your description here"
  Write-GLCArchive -VaultName $vaultName -FilePath $filePath -FolderPath $folderPath -Description $archiveDescription
  ```
- **Initiate a Job**: In order to start to read, its required to initiate job first. Use the `Start-GlacierJob` cmdlet to initiate a job in Glacier. You will need to specify the vault name, job type (`ArchiveRetrieval` or `InventoryRetrieval`), and any additional parameters required for the job type. Here's an example of initiating an archive retrieval job:

  ```
  $vaultName = "<vault-name>"
  $jobParameters = @{
      Type = "<job-type>"
      Description = "My inventory retrieval job"
  }
  Start-GlacierJob -VaultName $vaultName -JobParameters $jobParameters
  ```
- **Read Data from Glacier**: Use the `Get-GlacierJobOutput` cmdlet to read data from Glacier. You will need the job ID of the retrieval job that you initiated to retrieve the data from Glacier. Replace `<vault-name>` with your vault name and `<job-id>` with your job ID:

  ```
  $vaultName = "<vault-name>"
  $jobId = "<job-id>"
  Get-GlacierJobOutput -VaultName $vaultName -JobID $jobId -FilePath "<your-local-path>"
  ```

  This cmdlet will download the output of the Glacier retrieval job to the specified file path on your local machine.

Please note that Glacier is a cold storage service, and retrieving data from Glacier can take several hours. It's designed for long-term storage of data that is infrequently accessed.

Comment: this code is not quite correct:


`PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-AWSCredential -AccessKey A*****S -SecretKey 6******B -`StoreAs AwsGlacierConnect
`
`PS C:\Windows\system32> New-GLCVault -VaultName MYGLACIER2
`New-GLCVault : No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.
`At line:1 char:1
`+ New-GLCVault -VaultName CLEVO2
`+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
`    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: `(Amazon.PowerShe...wGLCVaultCmdlet:NewGLCVaultCmdlet) [New-GLCVault], 

How should I write it correctly?

Comment: looks like you have troubles with credentials, try running this command as well `Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName <credential-name>` or go through this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html

Comment: `Set-AWSCredential ` runs smoothly on my side i.e. w/o any visible errors. Also `Get-AWSCredential -ListProfileDetail` shows me my successfully added credentials. What else could be wrong there?

Comment: `Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName <credential-name>` works flawlessly, but then I get another error:

`PS C:\Windows\system32> New-GLCVault -VaultName clevo -Region us-west-2`
`New-GLCVault : User: arn:aws:iam::24xxxxxxxxx54:user/sen-backup is not authorized to perform: glacier:CreateVault on resource: arn:aws:glacier:us-west-2:24xxxxxxxxx54:vaults/clevo` `because
no identity-based policy allows the glacier:CreateVault action`
`At line:1 char:1
+ New-GLCVault -VaultName clevo -Region us-west-2`